# python logging in django view causes TypeError

Tags: python, django, logging

I set the logging as below

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
)

logger = logging.getLogger('myapp.views')

def my_view(request):
    ...
    try:
        parse_file_using_regex(file):
        ...
    except IndexError as ie:
        logger.debug('content of file not proper:',ie)
    except ValueError as ve:
        logger.debug('caused value error')
```

When a valuError occurs ,I get the following output

```
...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 768, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 648, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 436, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 306, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
....Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 768, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 648, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 436, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 306, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
2012-06-21 09:13:47,909 DEBUG caused value error
```

Can somebody help me figure this out? Why do I get a TypeError?

using pdb,and including the following in `getMessage(self)` of python2.6/logging/**init**.py

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
print msg,sef.args

...> /usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py(307)getMessage()
-> print msg,sef.args
(Pdb) msg
'parsing subtitle file:'
(Pdb) self.args
('/home/me/dev/python/django/myapp/media/testpath/testfile.srt',)
(Pdb)
```

Comment: could you print the msg and self.args values? just go to the "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py" file, write "import pdb; pdb.set_trace(); print msg, self.args" in line 305 and run it again

Comment: I have updated the question with the results of the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your logging message a %s value, so it would be like this:

```
logger.debug('content of file not propper: %s', ie)
```

I have used the logger in a different way also, just adding the message directly like this:

```
logger.debug('content of file not propper: %s' % ie)
```

which seems to me a lot more straight foward.

About the pdb, it is a really nice way to debug your program, I recommend it 100% :)